# Angular 5 and ADAL - working npm package (incl. AOT)

Tags: npm, adal, angular5

Is there any working npm package for ADAL and Angular 5 (AOT build)?

I did try few, but everyone had some problems.

`adal-angular4plus`

> ERROR in node_modules/adal-angular4plus/adal4.service.d.ts(40,25): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'adal'.
>   node_modules/adal-angular4plus/adal4.service.d.ts(48,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'adal'. Installing `@types/adal-angular` nor `@types/adal` helped.

`ng2-adal`

> Did not work in AOT

`ng2-adal-aot`

> `acquireToken()` after injecting the iframe it refreshes automatically the `appModule`. Hard to explain. But imagine the situation where you do a http request in ngOnInit of a component which is hosrted by appModule and there is a httpInterceptor which calls inside `acquireToken()` - the appModule gets refreshed so it is neverending cycle.

Comment: Actually I'm struggling to have adal-angular4plus to work as well. You will be able to get a token, but it looks like it's not able to renew any token. I'm always facing a `Token renewal operation failed due to timeout`.

Comment: you could try `adal-angular5` as well. It's still little buggy, but I managed to have it work, and even in case of token renewal.

Comment: `adal-angular5` gives me this AOT error: `ERROR in node_modules/adal-angular5/adal5.service.d.ts(1,22): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'adal-angular'. 'xxx/node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try 'npm install @types/adal-angular' if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing 'declare module 'adal-angular';`. Needless to say, the `npm install @types/adal-angular` does not help :(

Comment: Alright, the problem was this https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal/issues/85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [ezcode-adal-angular5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ezcode-adal-angular5)? This component:

- was created from a angular 5 cli project and leveraged adal.js internally.
- supports Angular 5 projects.
- was able to authenticate users using Azure AD.
- was able to secure the route components same as adaljs for angularjs.

you can also check a sample from https://github.com/frankchen76/EZCode-Adal-Angular5-Sample

Answer (score 1):

In order to have adal-angular4plus work, add `import { adal } from 'adal-angular';` in the .ts file where you define your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You may also want to check [adal-angular5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular5), an Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) wrapper package for Angular 5.  Uses HttpClient and HttpClientModule.

A [working example](https://github.com/jcmontx/angular5-adal-example) using adal-angular5.

Comment: I did try it and it did not work for me. I was facing this issue: https://github.com/grumar/adal-angular5/issues/24

Comment: Angular 5.2.8 has introduced URL serialization so special characters are only encoded where needed.  But it broke Open Id connect token readability from hash.  A quick fix is:   window.location.hash = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);  Detail explanation can be found in [Anthony Girett's blog](http://anthonygiretti.com/category/adal-angular5/)